# Redirect authentication via OAuth2 to Google login page

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api

I created a web app that allows users to connect their google calendar using OAuth2. And so far everything is working the way I've wanted it to be. Now my concern is, when a user clicks the link to authenticate his account, I want it to forcefully redirect to the google login page. Right now, when he clicks the link and his google account has an on-going session in that specific browser, the login page no longer appears. Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: If the user is already logged into google and you already have authorization to access the data then the oauth callback will be posted to with the login data.  There is no need for the user to 'login' to google again.  You've done the OAuth dance.  All is well

Answer (score 0):

If you set the parameter *approval_prompt* to *force*, you should be able to forcefully show the auth screen every time. More details about this parameter are documented [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl).

Answer (score 0):

the only way to do that is to force a full logout from that client (browser, app, etc). You can do that by using:
https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=  and add the redirect as "continue" parameter.
This will logout from everywhere so the user might not be happy if he/she didn't do that on purpose.

I would go with asking for permissions again if you want to make the users "feel" like they are actually login into your app again (i assume that why you want this approach).

Google also has a "switch user" option, but I haven't use it and it's really hard to know if the user will be asked for user and pass or the user will be automatically authenticated because he/she is already logged in another tab in the browser.